# How can I find specific directories using Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have a batch file that finds last modified directory in the path

```
for /f "delims= %%x in (' dir / ad /od /b "C:\Path") do set newest=%%x
```

I need to modify this script to only look for certain folders and find a last modified one. For example, if the path contains 4 directories(Red, Blue, Green, Yellow), I want to let command to only look for 2 directories(Blue, Green), and find the latest modified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
for /f "delims=" %%x in (
  'dir / ad /od /b "C:\Path" ^| Findstr /i "Blue Green" '
    ) do set newest=%%x
```

Will filter in an `or` fashion all lines containing Blue or Green in any position in the line.

Comment: You missed the close " for delims.

Comment: I would make that into a regular expression so that it matches the beginning and end of the word otherwise it could match a partial.

Comment: @soja Thanks for the hint, changed.

Comment: This works well without changing much in original script. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

With directory names like that you'll even get away without the findstr:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR/B/AD-L/OD "C:\PATH\B?UE" "C:\PATH\GR?EN"') DO (
    SET "NEWEST=%%A"
SET NEWEST
PAUSE
```